# Make an object base on built-in data types with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes named `ApprenticeshipDto` an `Apprenticeship` like the following

```
public class ApprenticeshipDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PersonFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PersonLastName { get; set; }
}

 public class Apprenticeship
 {
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public Person Person { get; set; }      
 }

public class Person
{
    public  string FirstName { get; set; }
    public  string LastName { get; set; }  
}
```

this is how I am trying to Map ApprenticeshipDto to Apprenticeship:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApprenticeshipDto, Apprenticeship>();

Apprenticeship a = Mapper.Map<Apprenticeship>(Apprdto);
```

The problem is all the properties are mapped correctly but not the `Person`.
Is that possible to tell Automapper to create Person property and automatically assign `PersonFirstName` and `PersonLastName`  to the `FirstName` and `LastName` of the Person object?

Comment: Mehrdad I suggest you ditch AutoMapper altogether. You are putting behaviour in the wrong place (the mapping configuration). Be explicit and put behaviour in your classes. You can add a method in `ApprenticeShip` called `ToDto` that returns the `ApprenticeshipDto`. It is a much better solution long-term. Trust me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to tell AutoMapper to map the DTO properties to a destination object property by using a [custom value resolver](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers) class. The resolver maps the `PersonFirstName` and `PersonLastName` properties to a new `Person` object:

```
// create the resolver class 
// -> extract person info from DTO and return a new Person object
public class CustomResolver : ValueResolver<ApprenticeshipDto, Person>
{
    protected override Person ResolveCore(ApprenticeshipDto source)
    {
        return new Person
            {
                    FirstName = source.PersonFirstName,
                    LastName = source.PersonLastName
            };
    }
}
```

Then use the new custom resolver class in the AutoMapper configuration before mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApprenticeshipDto, Apprenticeship>();

var adto = new ApprenticeshipDto
{
    Id = 10,
    PersonFirstName = "John",
    PersonLastName = "Doe"
};
// configure custom mapping
Mapper.CreateMap<ApprenticeshipDto, Apprenticeship>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Person, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
Apprenticeship a = Mapper.Map<Apprenticeship>(adto);
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", a.Id, a.Person.FirstName, a.Person.LastName);
```

The output is as expected:

```
10 - John - Doe
```